Extracted Bands 4 1 3: Vegetation is green not red
I'm trying to determine impervious surface area of a given parcel. The first step I've tried was to use the Extract Bands Raster Function tool to help distinguish between different land use (pavement vs vegetation, for example), using the Combination 4 1 3.
Per the directions I've been following (Calculate Impervious Surface, this should have resulted in the vegetation appearing red, roads gray, roofs blue/gray. My results, however, show vegetation as green, roads/ pavement appear gray/green, and roofs are gray. There is some pink (mainly on cars). Did I do something wrong, or is this a normal result that won't skew my analysis? I'm using near map imagery as my raster layer and ArcGIS Pro 3.2


What does band 4 1 3 refer to in your raster? The sample data is RGB(unknown), unknown is probably near infra red making the band combination 4 1 3 = NIR,R,B which sounds about right, what bands in your raster have those wavelengths?

Admittedly, I'm not very familiar with raster data. How would I know what the bands refer to/ what bands in my raster have those wavelength? My understanding of assigning the 4 1 3 band classification was to help more clearly distinguish between impervious and pervious land use. In the image I shared above, however, it looks like some of the sidewalks/ trees have similar coloration which I am afraid will skew my results.

Do you have a close relationship with the agency that commisioned the imagery or did you download this raster from a government source? The first step is to identify the bands, look at the metadata or project specification if available, if not you should turn to your provider. It might be that the imagery does not have a near infra red band, if this is the case you can't perform the impervious surface analysis. If you're prepared to have a wild stab in the dark it's possible that the NIR band is 1 which would make your band combination 1 2 4, try that and see if it becomes redder.
